# Setting "rvm use ruby-1.9.3" permanently?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have to type `rvm use ruby-1.9.3` every time I login to my server.
How do I do this permanently?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here you go:

```
rvm --default use ruby-1.9.3
```

For more details, such as providing a default gemset, please read the [following](http://beginrescueend.com/rubies/default/).

Comment: Just did this, ran "rake routes" and got a stacktrace so large it's outside the scrollable history of my terminal. FWIW, did successfully set the RVM version permanently.